# Unresolved reference: kotlinx - Kotlin 1-0-0-rc-1036

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm working in an Android App and a few days ago I updated my Kotlin version from **1.0.0-beta-1103** to the release candidate **1.0.0-rc-1036** and now I can't run my app for something related to Kotlin Android Extensions.

I use the `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` just like the official blog says http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/02/kotlin-1-0-release-candidate-is-out/ but my app doesn't recognize any view from any layout.

This is what appears on the console:

> Error:(20, 8) Unresolved reference: kotlinx
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
>
> Compilation error. See log for more details

Please help me, I'm losing my mind!

**Update:**

This is my buildScript in global`build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = "1.0.0-rc-1036"
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
        // quickly to Android tooling updates
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

The dependencies listed in the app `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Google
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'

    // Kotlin
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    // Square
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    // ReactiveX
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-support-v4:0.2.0'

    // DBFlow
    kapt 'com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Compiler:2.2.1'
    compile "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Core:2.2.1"
    compile "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow:2.2.1"

    // Otros
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'

    // SQLite Assets Helper
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'

    // Crashlytics Kit
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

This is an import that I'm using:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_all_quizzes.*
```

Comment: Could you include your `buildscript` and the plugins listed in your `build.gradle`? And what is the import you're using?

Comment: A clean build doesn't work?

Comment: No, I already tried with a clean but it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"` 
should be defined in the project-local `build.gradle` file for now.

Comment: Thank you! I moved the buildScript block code to the app/build.gradle file and this solved my problem

Comment: I have one app with a separate kotlin module and the app module that should have kotlin too. I've moved the build script form global to local `build.gradle` but i have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Your kotlin stdlib compile dependency should (at least while not stable) be the same as the kotlin android studio plugin version

```
...
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
...
buildscript {
   ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.0-rc-1036'
...
```

Comment: This is not the problem because the kotlin android studio plugin version is the same as **kotlin-stdlib** and **kotlin-gladle-plugin**